# How do I make a semi-transparent border with CSS?

Tags: html, css, border, transparency, padding

I have a popup and I want to give it a transparent border. I have these properties set:

```
li.sub-nav ul.megamenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-top: 3px;
    -moz-background-clip: border; /* Firefox 3.6 */
    -webkit-background-clip: border; /* Safari 4? Chrome 6? */
    background-clip: border-box;
}

.nav-top-container .megamenu {
    background: #005525;
    background: rgba(0, 85, 37, .98);
    border-top: 1px solid #227b33;
    border-bottom: #005525;
    border-bottom:8px solid rgba(0, 85, 37, .98);
}
```

I added the `background-clip` properties according to [this article](https://css-tricks.com/transparent-borders-with-background-clip/), I also tried setting it to `content` and `padding`, but it isn't working.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle? We need a way to see what you're seeing. Your CSS has `display: none`, which is probably why you can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) on the `padding`, as it is the closest box-model to the border. The default is `border`, which causes the background to be behind the transparent border.

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}
div {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 15px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);

  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I indicated in my comment to @LGSon, the issue you are frustrated with is that the `background` of your element extends into the border area.  An easy workaround for this is to apply that background to a nested element like in the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/yqx7abd8/

```css
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/800/city/1) center / cover;
}

.border {
  margin: 30px;
  border: 15px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="content">
    <p>
    My Content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```